# Android request data from json Graph Api Disappears from the array

Tags: android, facebook, api, graph

My question is: Why does the data disappear from the arraylist. When I'm logged in the data is being added to the array, when I close the application without clicking the logout button and reopen the application again the array is empty.
The code bellow is working fine.

```
    private ArrayList<String> allPostsStory = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> allPostsMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("LOGIN RESULT", loginResult.toString());


            // GRAPH API Bellow

            //GETTING POSTS
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/me/feed",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            // JSON GETS THE DATA
                            JSONObject jsonData=response.getJSONObject();

                            try {

                                JSONArray postsData = jsonData.getJSONArray("data");
                                if(postsData != null){

                                    for(int i = 0; i < postsData.length(); i++){
                                        JSONObject story = postsData.getJSONObject(i);
                                        if(story.has("story")){
                                            String storyMessage = story.getString("story");
                                            allPostsStory.add(storyMessage);
                                        }
                                        if(story.has("message")){
                                            String postMessage = story.getString("message");
                                            allPostsMessages.add(postMessage);
                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                                Log.d("Array of Stories","" + allPostsStory);
                                Log.d("Array of Messages", "" + allPostsMessages);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("JSON", "error" + e.toString());
                            }

                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? or that's how supposed to work?
Thank you.